# Userscript stops working on AJAX loaded pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, refresh, greasemonkey

I am making a userscript for greasemonkey that replaces the link to another site link. Its working fine on other sites. But on Google search it just works on the first page. When I click on **2nd** page (or any other number) or the **Videos** , it stops working. It seems that this has something to do with the page refresh. How can I make it work on every page?

Here is my code

```
// ==UserScript==
// @include     http://*
// @include     https://*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

this.$ = this.jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').each(function(){
        this.href = this.href.replace('youtube.com/watch?v=', 'ytpak.com/?component=video&task=view&id=');
    });
```

Comment: Quick guess: your `@require` rule has `http` so script stopping works on pages that use `https`

Comment: Also, Google search pages use AJAX-based reload instead of "normal" reload as I remember, so your script will be run only once.

Comment: That first page of Google is also on `https`. But working fine there.

Comment: So is there a way to make it work?

Comment: You must hook into google custom AJAX reload event, that is fired after clicking on "Next page" link, and run your function after it, every time.